# In emacs lisp how can I append a string to a file that I don't like to open?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I need to **append** a string `S`(belonging to no buffer) to a special file `F`, but since I hope this operation takes as little time as possible I don't want `F` opened as a buffer.

AFAIK, there is a built-in function in emacs called `write-region`, but this requires the content to be written into `F` inside one of the buffers(while in my case there is no guarantee that `S` should be such a string). How can I make it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`(write-region <STRING> nil <FILENAME> 'append)`

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you try something like:

```
(defun my-append-string-to-file (s filename)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert s)
    (write-region (point-min) (point-max) filename t)))
```

**EDIT**: Apparently, as @Stefan answered, `write-region` is capable of appending a string to a file, so I would recommend using his answer instead.

Comment: It seems a solution. But is it possible not to create the temp buffer at all?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Emacs does not provide a pure file interface (open, read etc.). However, Emacs is really efficient at working with buffers, so this should be really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you want to achieve but something like this might do the trick ... you can just put the path to the file you want to append to in place of /path/to/F.

```
(defun interactive-append (something)
  (interactive "sAppend S to F:")
  (shell-command (format "echo '%s' >> /path/to/F" something)))
```

Comment: `shell-command` takes a lot of time since it needs to invoke external shell, right?

Comment: This will not work outside of Unix, right?